# Does the zero operation on the set of integers defined by a binary operation x*y=0 for all x,y have a neutral element?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that in general, 0 is the identity element for addition of integers and 1 is the identity element for multiplication of integers. 
Let's consider the ‘zero’ operation on Z defined by
      x ∗ y = 0 for all x, y.

There's no neutral element for this binary operation, correct?

Comment: Your set is not clearly defined. Can you give a better definition of what set we are talking about? I mean, what element for example is in this set?

Comment: It's just the set of all integers s.t x*y=0 for all x,y

Comment: That makes no sense. A set is described as "all integers that satisfy this condition". Your description is not like this, because "$\forall x,y:x\cdot y=0$" is simply a false statement. Can you provide an example of an element of this set?

Comment: in this case, the condition would be the zero operation where x*y=0. For addition between x and y, one would need to negate the other for the sum to be 0. For multiplication, one would need to be zero.

Comment: I have no idea what in the world you just asked. Please, can you first simply tell me what are the elements of your set? Because I know of no integer for which $x\cdot y=0$ would be true for all pairs of integers.

Comment: My apologies, I'm not sure how else to phrase this...I am talking about a binary operation on the set of integers that combine two elements x,y in Z such that the operation between x and y equal to 0...

Comment: OOOOh, now I understand. Well then, please edit your question so that it is clear that you **defined** a **new** operation on the set of integers. Otherwise, people (like me) will read * and assume you mean the standard multiplication.

Comment: With your operation, can you find a $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $1 \star y = 1$?  If not, is there a neutral element?

Comment: under addition, y must be 0; and under multiplication, y must be 1...

Comment: Please look up the definition of neutral element. It "must" not be any specific element. It must be an element with a specific property relative to the given operation.

Comment: yes, and that is why I said there was no neutral element in my initial question....just needed confirmation to make sure I was understanding it correctly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neutral element for the $*$ operation should be $e$ with the property that, for every $x$, $e*x=x*e=x$. But
$$
e*1=0
$$
*for every* $e$, so no element can be neutral.